# Apache Ignite difference between ignite.getOrCreateCache() vs ignite.cache()

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database

I would like to clarify the differences between the following:

`ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);`

and

`ignite.cache("cacheName")`

The documentation on `cache()` says it

> Gets an instance of IgniteCache API.

As for `getOrCreateCache`,

> Gets existing cache with the given name or creates new one with the given configuration.

But they both return `IgniteCache`. Thank you!

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `getOrCreateCache` you can provide cache configuration that will be used to create new cache in case it doesn't exist yet. `cache` method will return `null` in this case.

Comment: But if the cache exists they will return the same thing? So they are basically the same apart from the ability of `getOrCreateCache` to create a new cache?